# C# Array, String, error

Tags: c#, visual-c++

```
        int i;
        int [,] Prices = new int [2, 7]{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{700,600,500,400,300,200,100}};
        string[,] City = new string [2,1]{{"A"},{"B"}}; 
        bool found = false;
        for (i = 0; i <= City.Length -1; i++)
          // for (y = 0; y <= City.Length - 1; y++)


        {
            if (LstDestinationCity.Text == City[i]) <<-- i get error here
          {
```

im planing to do a program that if i select A city i get first row if B city i get 2 row

Comment: Please concretize your question...

Answer (score 3):

I think that's because City[i] "don't contain anything" you should check City[i,0]

```
if (LstDestinationCity.Text == City[i,0])// this should access the first element which is the text you are looking for
```

Comment: Was just about to write the same :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it as

```
if (LstDestinationCity.Text == City[i,i])
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this would crash the application as it is. When he try to access City[1,1]

Answer (score 0):

Your `City` variable does not need to be a two dimensional array.  If you change it to a one dimensional array you can access the values with one index instead of 2.

```
string[] City = new string [2]{"A","B"};
```